# Linearly Dependent Random Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables

Intuitively, what is meant to be captured by the notion of linearly dependent (real-valued) random-variables?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "dependent random variables"? The word "dependent" does not mean "linearly dependent" in probabiliity

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> The covariance is sometimes called a measure of "linear dependence" between two random variables. That does not mean the same thing as in the context of linear algebra. When the covariance is normalized, one obtains the correlation matrix. From it, one can obtain the Pearson coefficient, which gives the goodness of the fit for the best possible linear function describing the relation between the variables. In this sense covariance is a linear gauge of dependence.

Comment: So when $\text{Cor}(X,Y) = 1$ or $-1$ one has perfect linear dependence, and when one has $\text{Cor}(X,Y) = 0$ one has perfect linear independence? Is this the way to think about it?